# Convert local datetime to UTC BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, timezone

My datetime data is stored as a local datetime and local timezone, given two columns. First column contains local datetime and a second one local timezone (see the picture below):

[image]

How can i create a single column with datetime in UTC?

So far i've tried:

```
SELECT
        localdatetime, localtimezone,
        PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%b %d, %Y, %r', LocalDateTime, "UTC") AS parsed_datetime
    FROM `xx`.yy.zz
    WHERE Localtimezone = "Europe/Ljubljana"
```

But the result i get is obviously wrong, since BQ doesn't know from which timezone it is converting.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery will automatically convert to UTC, so what you need to specify is really the timezone you are converting from.

Try the following instead:

```
select 
    localdatetime 
    , localtimezone 
    , PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%b %d, %Y, %r', LocalDateTime, localtimezone ) AS parsed_datetime
from sample_data
```

For more information refer to the documentation here
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#parse_timestamp